# Django Package on virtual environment Malfunction after a certain time after reinstallation on cPanel share hosting server on deployment

Tags: django, deployment, shared-hosting, virtual-environment

I'm hosting a django project on a Shared hosting server cpnal that use CloudLinux.
I've respect all the step and requirements to host a django project on a shared hosting server
using passanger_wsgi.py.
When I create a python application, getting a virtual enviromnent and installing all required package for my django project to work properly everything work  very well and my application itself doesn't have any error and I have done all the test. But after a certain time, takes one or two weeks my python app get some packages error, some of them(mysqlclient, pillow, ....) and I'm obliged to delete the application, recreate it again and reinstall all the package to make everything work again.

I've try to solve the error with the hosting service admin -> installing the lsapi and also install the python development package for Mysql.
By my side I've tried to change the Mysql client package with pymsql  and other.
But still getting that error but it's periodic after one or two weeks after reinstallation.

So please what can I do. I need some help before taking the decison of trying another hosting service.
Is there something i'm missing, please help me.